# Open source resource manager and reservation system for complex hardware setups

Tags: networking, scheduling, cloud, resource-management

I have a rather complex hardware setup that I need to replicate multiple times and then use the instances of that setup in parallel by multiple users.

For simplicity, let’s just say that the setup involves 2 virtual machines (Ubuntu), on 2 different servers, each one communicating with an external hardware switch. Then all are connected to a hardware router. Entities can be accessed over SSH and/or REST API. I have multiple setups like the one above.

Is there a software platform that I can use to manage multiple instances of the above setup? By managing them I mean both keeping the software updated on each entity in the setup and also having the ability to reserve each setup for a certain user of the platform.

Comment: Does Amazon AWS not do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/).

Is an open-source infrastructure-as-configuration software tool.

It can build data center infrastructure through a declarative configuration language like HCL or  JSON.